# opacity and z-index on stacking order of elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, opacity

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8aAKz/3/)** is my code, if you click on junction of divs you can see that divleft is the greatest stack in order. but I'm trying to set the greatest stack as "divright". z-index is not working,

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add this to your divright class:

```
position: relative
```

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle and it was working fine.  Upon applying position relative to divright, it will then overlay ontop of divleft causing the junction to disappear since you have no opacity on divright.  Adding these to divright should solve the problem position: relative;  opacity:0.7;  Also what browser are you using, could be a compatibility problem as well.

Comment: sorry that was not working at the first time I tried but that's working now, thanks.

Comment: I have confirmed that this works. Show us your new jsfiddle @ocanal.

Answer (score 1):

z-index is nothing without position: relative or absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/8aAKz/14/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/lupos/8aAKz/16/

I think your problem is that they did not have the same display style. One was floated and one wasn't. If you make them both block and force the over lap z-index works fine.

N/M duh. Position was the issue as the others said... which I also added.  :P